# How to Insert System.Datetime object into SqlServer via DbCommand with parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I try to do this for couple of hours.

```
            Database db = DBUtil.GetInstance().GetDataBase();
            DbCommand cmd = db.GetSqlStringCommand(@"INSERT INTO [XXX] (
            ...
                                                                  ,[FirstDate]
            ...
            ) VALUES ('@FirstDate',...");

            db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@FirstDate", DbType.Date, DateTime.Now );
```

But I always get this exception information below.

> {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed
>   when converting date and/or time from character string.

what should I do for the conversion ?  Or pick up another DbType ? DbType.DateTime2 ?

Comment: I generally prefer to use DateTime2. It's more flexible and is a recommended practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add quote for parameter in Insert Statement. *(Values('@FirstDate'))*

```
    Database db = DBUtil.GetInstance().GetDataBase();
    DbCommand cmd = db.GetSqlStringCommand(@"INSERT INTO [XXX] (
    ...
                                                          ,[FirstDate]
    ...
    ) VALUES (@FirstDate,...");

   db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@FirstDate", DbType.DateTime, DateTime.Now );
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what the type is in your database if it's Date or DateTime.

```
// full date and time
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@FirstDate", DbType.DateTime, DateTime.Now );
```

or

```
// just the date portion
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@FirstDate", DbType.Date, DateTime.Now.Date );
```

Comment: That's not the problem here - see minmin's answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet, ah, yes, I see that now...but at least give me half credit for getting the other problem! :-)